# Formatting links from HTML

Tags: formatting, screen-scraping, href

I am trying to find a guide to explains how browsers format "links" that are contained within href tags.  For example:

What does the browser do with the following types of tags:

- /attorneys

  ?p=1&Name=A

  attorneys

The reason I want the info is because I am currently formatting links in a very inefficient way, and would like to write my own script to handle this task.  Everytime I create a script on my own, though, it misses the mark and some links inevitably dont work - so there must be some rules that I am missing.

Thanks for the help!
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- /attorneys => replace the the path, only the host is unchanged
- ?p=1&Name=A => replace the query string, the host and path are unchanged
- attorneys => replace the filename, the host and path up to the last / are
  unchanged

Most languages have a library that will do this for you, and that's what you should use. In ruby for example it's URI:

```
new_url = URI.join(current_url, href).to_s
```